# Classical nilpotent and solvable Lie algebras

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-algebras

In this question $F$ denotes a Field. We have the set of strictly upper triangular matrices of size $n \times n$ denoted by $n(n,F)$ is nilpotent of index $n$, so it is easy to check that the algebra $t(n,F)$  of  upper triangular matrices of size $n \times n$ is solvable, but what is its index of solvability? And how can we find it?

Comment: It would help to define explicitly what you mean by "index" of a solvable Lie algebra.    I guess the meaning of index for nilpotent Lie algebras is fairly clear: the smallest $n >0$ for which $x^n=0$ for all $x$.   (Is this question at research level?  If not, maybe it belongs at stackexchange)

Comment: Index of solvability of a Lie algebra $L$ is the smallest k>0 for which $L^{(k)}=0.$

Comment: $L^{(k)} = [L^{(k - 1)}, L^{(k - 1)}]$?

Comment: Lspice: Yes $L^{(k)}=[L^{(k−1)},L^{(k−1)}].$

Comment: Ycor: why the solvability length of $ n(d,F)$ is $⌈log_{2}d⌉$ (and  that of $t(d,F)$ is $⌈log_{2}d⌉+1)$?

Comment: @YCor, sorry, my only [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336831/classical-nilpotent-and-solvable-lie-algebras#comment841991_336831) was on the definition of $L^{(k)}$.  Was "[no, classical error](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336831/classical-nilpotent-and-solvable-lie-algebras#comment842000_336831)" a response to that?

Comment: @LSpice sorry I misread. Anyway one has to initialize at $L^{(0)}=L$ (in contrast to the lower central series initialized at $L^{1}=L$).

Comment: @AdamHamam it's an exercise. Try for $d\le 5$? This is not research-level anyway, MathSE is more suitable for such questions.